# Check openVPN client connected Debian

Tags: debian, openvpn

How can I check if my Debian OpenVPN client is connected? Is there a specific command I have to run? Or can I read it from the logfile?

Thanks.

Edit:
The answers below provide great value in debugging. I used the same open vpn credentials on two different systems, causing issues.

Comment: You want to check on the client that the client is connected to the VPN? Or you want to check on the server that client is connected to the VPN?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't clear to me if you are asking from the perspective of a client or server.  In any case one thing you should strongly look at is enabling the [management interface](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/79-management-interface.html) on your OpenVPN daemon with this configuration option.

```
management 127.0.0.1 6001
```

With the management interface enabled you can connected to whatever port you setup for this purpose using netcat/telnet.  Then you can issue the `status` command, or many other commands to determine exactly what is going on from the daemons perspective.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few methods, depending on what exactly you're trying to achieve. If you want to check if the client is running and you're using Debian's initscript, you can use the `service` command:

```
% sudo service openvpn status mammon; echo $?
 * VPN 'mammon' is running
0
```

If you want to check that the client thinks it is connected to the server, you can check the routing table for the VPN subnet or local interface existence:

```
% ip route | grep -q 10.8.0.1; echo $?
0
% ip link show dev tun0 > /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

If you want to check that the client is connected and the server is contactable, ping the server:

```
% ping -c1 -w5 -q 10.8.0.1 > /dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Where do you get the VPN subnet (10.8.0.1)?

Comment: Ping not working on macOS `ping: invalid option -- w`

Answer (score 4):

While I think @mgorven get a good answer, I'd like to propose another one which kind of puts the problem into a different perspective.

If one is using `/etc/network/interfaces` for configuring the network, it's possible to use it to control client OpenVPN tunnels.  It goes like this:

1. Use *custom* name of the tunnel device for the OpenVPN's `dev` option, for instance, have

   ```
   dev mytun
   ```

   in the OpenVPN configuration file.

   Let's say the config file is

   ```
   /etc/openvpn/client.conf
   ```
2. Set up an entry for that device in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file, like this:

   ```
   iface mytun inet manual
       pre-up   /etc/init.d/openvpn start client
       pre-down /etc/init.d/openvpn stop  client
   ```

Having set things up this way, you can now do

```
# /sbin/ifup mytun
# /sbin/ifdown mytun
```

Now back to the original question — `iface` sections in the networking configuration file also support the `post-up` directives which could be used for *scripting* the "tunnel is ready" events.

Yet another approach, for a Desktop machine, might be using a visual tool like [TunTun](http://code.google.com/p/tuntun/) to manage OpenVPN tunnels.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu there is a file holding the current OpenVPN status at `/var/run/openvpn.openvpn.status`

It looks to be the same as output of `status` command of management interface but you don't need to enable it in OpenVPN.

You can do some processing of it in scripts, i.e. check if the counters increase over time.

Answer (score -2):

```
ping -c  1 whoami.ultradns.net
```

EDIT:
`curl https://ipapi.co/json`

Returns your IP address (of your client).
So very easy to see if your VPN is connected / what VPN server you are connected via e.g a Foreign country.

No config required.

Comment: This identifies a DNS server, not a VPN server.